# connecting remote mysql server in web2py

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

How to connect to a remote mysql server in web2py?
I tried this:

```
db = DAL('mysql://root:password@ipaddress/portal')
```

But got the following error:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.4.20.61' (113)")

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running? If so, is it on the default port (otherwise, you need to specify the port after the ip address)?

Comment: Can you tell output of this `cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf` ?